# Create different model architectures in loop

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks, model, keras

I'm building a NN using keras and I'd like to build different architectures.
My question: Can I create several models with a different number of layers at once? (e.g. using a loop).

It should be something like:
`for (i in 1:10)` create `i` models with `i` number of layers.

I would like to know if something like this is generally possible.
I'm using the `keras_model_sequential()` function.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.